# Could no use registered function in UFT/QTP

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I have associated the following function to a tests in order to select a row in a java table when a the row text matches an expected value :

```
Public Function GetRowWithCellText(ByRef oJTable, sColName, sText)
bChkText=FALSE
iRowCount=oJTable.GetROProperty("rows")
    For iCounter=0 to iRowCount-1
       sGetCellText=oJTable.GetCellData(iCounter, sColName)
        If instr(sText, sGetCellText)>0 Then
             bChkText=TRUE
             GetRowWithCellText=iCounter               
        End If
   Next
    ReportingFunction bChkText, "Row with desired text"      
End Function
RegisterUserFunc "JavaTable", "GetRowWithCellText", "GetRowWithCellText", TRUE
```

The function is well registered and I got it in the list of available functions for a java table.
However when trying to apply the function into a JavaTable in my application :

```
JTable.GetRowWithCellText msg.users.list.table.header.user , LOGIN
```

I get the following error :

```
 Object required: 'msg' 

 Line (122): "JTable.GetRowWithCellText msg.users.list.table.header.user , LOGIN".
```

Please note that UFT is not recoginising cols of my table so I had inserted its value manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used column index instead of column name and it worked , I guess there is an issue with special characters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the 'Object required' error that the value for 'msg' is not defined.  The first part of `msg.users.list.table.header.user` refers to an object named 'msg'.  If that object does not exist or has not be initialized, you may get that error.

You can break your statement up to confirm where the error is located.  Change this statement

```
JTable.GetRowWithCellText msg.users.list.table.header.user , LOGIN
```

To these statements

```
Dim user
Set user = msg.users.list.table.header.user
JTable.GetRowWithCellText user, LOGIN
```

When you re-execute, you should get an error on the second line if there was an issue with `msg`; otherwise you will get an error on the third line if it is truly an issue with your function.